# Tool to remember clipboard content

Tags: windows, gratis, clipboard

Often I use the same terms/sentances/code-segments and want to reuse them during development.

I could define snippets in my IDE but I want to use those anywhere and I want to be able to search in these snippets to find the right one fast with a few keywords I remember.

What (free) software can help me with that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would stongly suggest [Clipdiary](http://clipdiary.com). It is a powerful clipboard manager, which records every piece of data that goes to the Windows clipboard, meaning that you can easily retrieve any information that was once copied to the clipboard (if Clipdiary was running at that moment):

[image: Clipdiary]

Clipdiary clipboard utility saves not only text data, it also works with pictures, files, html links, text with formatting. You can easily reuse once copied pictures and even the whole files!

The features include:

- Support for text, images, files, and other clipboard data.
- Clipboard history is available after computer reboot.
- Data stored in history can be reused many times.
- Program automatically monitors clipboard changes, so there are no additional tasks for the user.
- Paste data directly into any application
- Fast copy data back to the clipboard
- Paste text without formatting (as plain text)
- Search through saved clipboard history
- Find data you once copied to the clipboard
- View the list of clips in the clipboard history viewer window
- Recover data accidentally replaced in the clipboard

Comment: Has anyone done security review of this app? I'd like to use it, but it does seem a bit risky, since sometimes you copy very sensitive information.

Comment: This app does not appear to be free.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/).

It is Open-Source and uses a database in the background to store all your clipboard content. You can use a very wide range of settings to adjust it to your needs.

How does it work?

- Use the Shortcut you defined to open the list of past clipboard contents.
- Select the one you want to use and copy it into your clipboard
- Insert wherever you want

[image: ditto]

You can also input anything in the searchbox at the bottom to limit the entries in the list to your matches.

I use it also in [*Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/) to speedup me writing an answer. Often I can reuse past used code segments and adjust them.

Or if I want to write a DB trigger i.e. and don't remember the exact syntax then I can just reuse an old one and adjust it in seconds.

Comment: Of all fonts you chose comic sans?

Comment: Oh yeah. Muahahaha. And it goes well with red-freehand-circles.

Comment: Although not the accepted answer, after 4.5 years this has the most upvotes. A good clipboard manager is a "must have" tool for me, so every time I see a question mentioning one I give it a thorough test drive. So far, nothing beats Ditto

Comment: I've been using Ditto since years now and I don't want to miss it! It's fully integrated into my workflow. `choco install firefox ditto` is my first subgoal in setting up windows devices.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CLCL](https://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html). It's very lightweight (425kb) and it binds to your Alt+C key.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Choice

[image: Clipjump Icon] [**Clipjump**](https://github.com/aviaryan/Clipjump) — my choice.

---

### 2. Demonstration

[image: Clipjump GIF]

---

### 3. Description

#### 1. Benefits

1. Open source.
2. Easy and fast for usage. In `Paste Mode` user need to press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, and then <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> keys for select items in a clipboard.
3. Galore features, [**API**](http://clipjump.sourceforge.net/docs/devList.html) for creating users [**Clipjump plugins**](http://clipjump.sourceforge.net/docs/plugins/index.html).
4. [**Detailed documentation**](http://clipjump.sourceforge.net/docs/).

#### 2. Disadvantages

1. The main developer [**stopped work on the project**](https://github.com/aviaryan/Clipjump/issues/136).

---

For more information see Clipjump [**official site**](http://clipjump.sourceforge.net/).