# Clipboard Buffer like in IntelliJ IDEa

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, copy-paste

IntelliJ IDEa, which is a development tool has this amazing feature, where it remembers what you copied and it allows you to paste different things you copied. You can 
- filter in your buffer by just typing. 
- remove stuff from buffer.
- simply paste stuff from the buffer or copy it to immediate clipboard again.

All of this by just pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

It looks on the image below.

Can I have something like this in Windows 10 with a piece of software? I would love it!

[image]

Comment: Try Clipjump. See [**my answer to another question**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/39662/23324). Thanks.

Comment: That's https://github.com/aviaryan/Clipjump

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10 you can use [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net). To make it more useful in everyday life you can set main hot-key to **ctr**+**shift**+**insert**, but be careful, because it can conflict with other programs hot-keys.

Comment: You beat me to it! Welcome aboard :-) Every few months I search for possible alternatives to my favourite apps, which include such clipboard functionality. After many years, I am still using Ditto because I cannot find anything better, or even close to it. this is the correct answer, for sure

Comment: Has anyone done a security review of the source of these Ditto and Clipjump apps? Clipboard can easily contain very sensitive information.